# No such module 'SwiftCharts' Xcode Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created an app in Xcode and Swift 4 that uses the external frameworks 'SwiftCharts'.

All works fine, however if I move the folder where the whole project and all its files are contained, I get the error message "No such module 'SwiftCharts'" appear after every "import SwiftCharts" in my project.

I need to submit my project as a university assignment but at the moment the only place the project will work is in my Documents folder on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the module by Right click the SwiftCharts and check by Show in Finder.
If it is not present in the folder, you need to copy it in the projects.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you read about Embedding Private Frameworks in Your Application Bundle:

> you normally specify the full path to the appropriate frameworks
>   directory. When you embed a framework inside a bundle, however, the
>   location of the framework is not fixed, so you have to use the
>   @executable_path placeholder to let the framework know its location is
>   relative to the current executable.
>
> Open an inspector for your framework target and select the Build tab.
>   Set the value of the Installation Directory build setting to
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks.

From this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880

Managing external references in any project is essential to understand.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17906331)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @kometen - I have done as you suggested and added the essential information from the link.